# API returns the last activity date even if asked not to

Tags: bug, api-v2, filter

Using the `/questions` method, I tried to get upvote and downvote counts, along with question Ids.  [This is the request](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/857455%3B857454?site=math&filter=!w-1qg-_wOmTqzZSU1Z) I sent:

```
http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/857455%3B857454?site=math&filter=!w-1qg-_wOmTqzZSU1Z
```

The `last_activity_date` is returned despite being excluded by the filter. I re-checked on [the docs page that the filter `!w-1qg-_wOmTqzZSU1Z` indeed excludes last_activity_date parameter](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=votes&ids=857455%3B857454&filter=!w-1qg-_wOmTqzZSU1Z&site=math).

Answer (score 1):

**Confirmed.**
The path seems to use a default sort key on `last_activity_date` and that corrupts the filter somehow. (I checked for caching by waiting more than 1 minute and by varying the question ids.)

If I create [a new filter and explicitly specify a sort key on votes](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=votes&ids=857455%3B857454&filter=!8IgsXbMxnbGlR3L4_diGD&site=math&run=true), it [worked for a time or two](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/857455%3B857454?order=desc&sort=votes&site=math&filter=!8IgsXbMxnbGlR3L4_diGD) (no `last_activity_date` returned).

But somehow it still inserts `last_activity_date` randomly on subsequent runs. I haven't figured out the pattern to it yet.

**As a partial workaround** for this bug, always specify a sort key that doesn't rely on a field not returned by the filter.

Comment: Here's a fun fact:  So far, adding `&type=jsontext` to the end of the request clears up the misbehavior!  This is flaky stuff.